# Apply dropdown to only main menu then list submenu without dropdown

Tags: wordpress, menu, wp-nav-walker

What is the best way to achieve keeping the first navbar-dropdown but then getting rid all of the trailing levels? So I'd like to keep `navbar-dropdown` on the main menu hover, but have all the submenus just be listed out.

I'll also like to keep the `has-dropdown is-hoverable` on just the main menu level and get rid of it on all of the submenus.

Picture for details:
[image]

Here is what my current Navwalker looks like:

```
class Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        $output .= "<div class='navbar-dropdown'>";
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        // Add your custom item classes here

        $custom_classes_from_menu = implode(' ', $item->classes); // turn the WP classes object array to string values

        $liClasses = 'navbar-item ' . $custom_classes_from_menu; // add the values to your classes list

        $hasChildren = $args->walker->has_children;
        $liClasses .= $hasChildren? " has-dropdown is-hoverable": "";

        if($hasChildren){
            $output .= "<div class='".$liClasses."'>";
            $output .= "\n<a class='navbar-link' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title."</a>";
        }
        else {
            $output .= "<a class='".$liClasses."' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title;
        }

        // Adds has_children class to the item so end_el can determine if the current element has children
        if ( $hasChildren ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'has_children';
        }
    }

    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){

        if(in_array("has_children", $item->classes)) {

            $output .= "</div>";
        }
        $output .= "</a>";
    }

    public function end_lvl (&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

        $output .= "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just change the menu structure in the admin area, so that the levels are nested the way you want?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, unfortunately, that's not going to work for me since I'm also introducing a mega menu and will need to nest the menu items properly so that I can pass in the class names to the menu items.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what structure you want in the end, but I've used the standard menu structure without a custom navwalker with a mega menu before, but if you need to do this in the code, then would it work if you just remove the `if($hasChildren){` clause?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, were you able to successfully do that on WordPress? I'm using the Bulma framework and having the hardest time.

Comment: Mine was a custom child theme based on twenty seventeen (I think - it was a while ago), so we weren't restricted by any code or css in a framework. Sorry I can't be of more help :)